# Does switch comes under control statements?

Tags: c

Switches which are part of c programming also gives us choices in coding So does it comes under the category of control statements?

Comment: It's a [C11 selection statement](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4). The Standard does not have the description of "control statement".

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: Yes, `switch` is one of the 4 types of control statements.

Comment: I'm very curious about the background for your questions? Why do you wonder? This kind of sounds like an exam question, something which we really shouldn't help you cheat with.

Comment: Actually I'm studying for my exams tomorrow so I came up with that doubt.  By the way thanks folks for answering and helping.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard describes statements in six categories: labeled statements, compound statements, expression and null statements, selection statements, iteration statements, and jump statements.

`switch` statements are in the category of selection statements. There is no category the C standard calls control statements.

Labeled statements are `identifier: statement`, which can be used with `goto identifier`, or `case constant-expression : statement` or `default : statement`, both of which are used inside `switch` statements.

Compound statements are `{ list of declarations or statements }`.

Expression or null statements are `expression ;` or just `;`.

Selection statements are `if …`, `if … else …`, and `switch` statements.

Iteration statements are `while`, `do`, and `for` statements.

Jump statements are `goto`, `continue`, `break`, and `return` statements.